# Contact form with PHP and formmail

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I've set up a contact form and I'm really happy with it now (I just need to work on some Javascript valiation which shouldn't be too hard). However I've used a nice fancy jQuery CAPTCHA box that I've found. The problem is that this has a dependancy on a PHP file and I know no PHP yet!

Basically all I want to do is if the CAPTCHA is valid then use formmail.pl to submit the data to my email address. I don't even know where to start with tackling this so I hope someone will be able to help me out?

I've been able to add in a simple redirect in which I' also like to keep in ideally.

Here are the URL's to take a look at:

Form - http://www.seogarden.co.uk/contact-form.shtml
PHP page - domain/captcha/captcha.php (sorry can only post 1 link)

Comment: Is there an API for the Captcha you use? I'm sure you can implement it with perl, Captcha's are usually quite straight forward.

Comment: No it's not using the google CAPTCHA. It's something that simply verifies that the user is human because they need to drag an image and drop it into a square. I've got it working fine, I just need to be able to send the data to the formmail using PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use ajax thru jquery to send data to server.

for example something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=Submit]').click(function(){
        var person_name = $("input[name=Name]").val();
        var company_name = $("input[name=companyName]").val();
        var your_position = $("input[name=position]").val();
        var email = $("input[name=email]").val();
        var website = $("input[name=website]").val();
        var tel = $("input[name=telephone]").val();
        var intrested = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").attr('name'); //thats just sample - real this needs bit more code
        var comments = $("textarea[name=Comment]").val();

        var query = "person_name="+person_name+"&company_name="+company_name+"&your_position="+your_position+"&email="+email+"&website="+website+"&tel="+tel+"&intrested="+intrested+"&comments="+comments;

        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "send_to_server.php",
           data: query,
           success: function(){
            alert("E-mail sent!");
                       }
        });
    });
});
```

What kind of database you use? where you want to send this data? send_to_server.php depends on that.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `jQuery` `Easy FormMail` plugin.... You dont need to know anything of `PHP`

`$('#formmail').EasyFormMail({to:'recipient@example.com'})`

https://github.com/Thiagoguelfi2012/jQuery-Easy-FormMail